# Difference between maximal graph and complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am confused with the definition of maximal graph. For instance, is a maximal graph on n vertices same as a complete graph with n vertices?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "maximal" graph. There's a maximal cycle-free graph, maximal planar graph, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something is maximal when you cannot incrementally add another thing to it, usually under the constraint of the graph/subgraph/structure still satisfying some property P.

For example, a matching M is maximal if you cannot add another edge e into M without breaking the rules of a matching (each vertex can only be used once). However, M may not be the maximum matching because the edges in M may have been chosen suboptimally. (And M, regardless of being maximal or maximum, is *certainly* not complete because that would violently break the conditions of M being a matching)

A complete graph is simply, connect every vertex to every other vertex. No rules.